# Why my chart is injected with some random padding inside my canvas?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I can't figure out why I'm not able to remove this random padding injected inside my line chart in Chart.js (file attached).

Here is a part of my chart configuration :

```
myChart.current = new Chart(canvasRef.current, {
      type: "line",
      data,
      options: {
        tension: 0.6,
        scales: {
          x: {
            display: false,
          },
          y: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
            external: (context) => {
              const tooltipModel = context.tooltip;

              if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                setShowTooltip(false);
                return;
              }

              setShowTooltip(true);
              const tooltipEl = tooltipRef.current;
              const currentTooltipWidth = tooltipEl.clientWidth;
              const currentTooltipHeight = tooltipEl.clientHeight;
              const currentTooltipCenterAlign = currentTooltipWidth / 2;

              let left =
                tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].element.x -
                currentTooltipCenterAlign;

              if (left < 0) {
                left = Math.abs(left);
              }

              let top =
                tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].element.y -
                currentTooltipHeight -
                offsetY;

              if (top < 0) {
                top = tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].element.y + offsetY;
              }

              const date = tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].label;
              const value = tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].raw;

              setPositionAndData(top, left, date, value);
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Thank you very much for your help :) !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNi5p.png

Comment: Please add minimal code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hi @Nik, I added the complete configuration object. This is enough to reproduce the issue ?